# How to get-or-create a unique child node in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I'm new to Neo4j, and playing around by trying to set up a music database. To start simple, I'm just playing with two labels:

- `Artist`
- `Song`

Obviously this is a parent-child relationship, where a `Song` is a child of an `Artist` (or possibly multiple `Artist`s), and might look something like:

```
(:Artist {name:'name'})-[:RECORDED]->(:Song {title:'title'})
```

I am making the following assumptions:

- Artist names are unique
- Song titles are *not* unique
- Duplicate ingest data is unavoidable

To give an example of what I'd like to do:

1. I ingest "Hallelujah" by Leonard Cohen. A new `Artist` node and `Song` node are created, with a `RECORDED` relationship
2. I ingest "Hallelujah" by Jeff Buckley. Again, new `Artist` and `Song` node are created, with a `RECORDED` relationship. The first "Hallelujah" `Song` is not associated with this new graph at all.
3. I ingest "Hallelujah" by Jeff Buckley again. Nothing happens.
4. I ingest "Lilac Wine" by Jeff Buckley. We reuse our old `Artist` node, but I have a new `Song` node with a `RECORDED` relationship

From what I can tell, using `MERGE` gets me close, but not quite there (it stops duplication of the `ARTIST`, but not of the `SONG`). If I use `CREATE`, then point number 3. doesn't work properly.

I guess I could add another property to the `SONG` label which tracks its `ARTIST` (and I can therefore make unique), but that seems a little redundant and unidiomatic of a graph database, no?

Does anyone have any bright ideas on the most succinct way of enforcing these relationships and requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge Artist first, and after Song:

```
WITH 'Leonard Cohen' AS ArtistName, 
     'Hallelujah'    AS SongTitle
MERGE (A:Artist {name:ArtistName})
WITH A, 
     SongTitle 
OPTIONAL MATCH p=(A)-[:RECORDED]->(:Song {title:SongTitle})
FOREACH (x in CASE WHEN p IS NULL THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
  CREATE (S:Song {title:SongTitle})
  MERGE (A)-[:RECORDED]->(S)
) 
WITH A, 
     SongTitle
MATCH p = (A)-[:RECORDED]->(:Song {title:SongTitle})
RETURN p
```

Comment: This does indeed work, although having now seen how complicated the syntax needs to be to achieve this, I'm inclined to just use a redundant `artist` property on my `Song`s just so I can write something like `MERGE (a)-[:RECORDED]->(s:Song {title:'Hallelujah',artist:'Leonard Cohen'})` (or maybe even do away with the `Artist` label altogether?!)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think song title is something you can rely on for uniqueness, especially if this graph includes covers of existing songs.

Determining some additional means to imply uniqueness is the way to go.

Artist is one way. Recorded date might be another piece of data to consider. If you're reading this from some other kind of database, there may be some other unique ID they use for uniqueness.

Whatever the case, once you have the fields that you want to use to determine uniqueness, MERGE your song node with all those fields present.